# Start NoMachine server session over SSH

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, lxde, nx

My host is Windows 10 64-bit.

I have a raspberry pi that I do not have direct access to.
Neither do I have access to the router it's connected to.

I simply use SSH to connect to it.

But, I need to change Port Forwarding, and to do that, I need to have access to a GUI.

So I am using NoMachine.

But whenever I try to do

```bsh
/usr/NX/bin/nxserver --startsession
```

I get:

```bsh
NX> 500 ERROR: Display cannot be empty.
```

I have found solutions for `Xvfb` but Raspberry Pi OS uses LXDE.

```bsh
Xvfb :99 -auth /home/username/.Xauthority -screen 0 1024x768x24 DISPLAY=:99 /etc/NX/nxserver -startsession
```

(Source: https://forums.nomachine.com/topic/launch-session-using-commandline-in-with-nomachine-5-ts)

How would I go about this in SSH using LXDE on a raspberry pi?

---

I apologize if nothing of what I'm saying makes sense.

Comment: Xvfb is a display server implementing the X11 display server protocol. It should not matter which desktop environment you are running (like LXDE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you SSH to the Pi, be sure to set up XForwarding:

```
ssh -X foo@pi
```

Then invoke whatever x client command you like; it's tradition to test this using `xeyes`

If this works as expected, you may not even need NoMachine, really, though I guess it's supposed to be faster.

Comment: Would this work on Windows?

Comment: I tried this on windows, but when I type `xeyes` I get command not found.

Comment: So, that just means xeyes is not installed on the Pi. Remember that when you SSH, you're not "on" Windows anymore, you're connected interactively to the live, real Pi, exactly the same way you would be if you were sitting in front of it at a terminal window.
Yes this will work on Windows but you will need an X-Server such as Cygwin or Xming

Comment: I know that I just didn't know if the `ssh -X` thing worked on windows.

Turns out the reason Xvfb wasn't working was because I typed `xvfb` instead of `Xvfb` because I'm used to windows and it's case sensitive in linux/unix.

Comment: Gotcha. So, as long as you have an xserver running on your windows machine, and your ssh client supports it (PuTTY does), yes, it'll work.